# Default shipping method

Tags: django, country, django-oscar

I am trying to write a shipping method base on both by country and also weight-base in Django-oscar. It seems the default shipping methods must also have these

```
     from oscar.apps.shipping.methods import Free, FixedPrice, NoShippingRequired
```

I do not required any of the above and would only provide discount for shipping through discounts.

How do I write by repository.py so I do not apply any of these oscar.apps.shipping.methods import Free, FixedPrice, NoShippingRequired

So I can just write my class Repository (CoreRepository):

Without writing

```
   methods += [NoShippingRequired()]

   methods += [FixedPrice()]

   methods += [Free()]
```

The method I have written is not code based but implemented through the shipping menu in the dashboard. I followed the following to set my shipping.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-oscar/H4tf20ujm8k

When testing, on the page 'Shipping Menu', both the 'HandDelivery', and my weight-based by country shipping method button is displayed to customer. Which means customer can click the HandDelivery button too even when customer is based internationally. I wished to disable that 'HandDelivery' button at the Shipping method page, so it is not an option for customers to select at all.

Another option is to attached a message to this button to make it clear to customers that clicking that button means arranging to collect item from warehouse within 1 week of reservation.

How do I display that the message to the customer? Customer is not taking onto the payment page. And an email is sent so items can be collected within 7 days? Like similar to argos, reserve, item, go to shop, pay, and collect. So I could change the discription of 'HandDelivery' to reserve. Then customer does not pay but pay upon collection. But how?

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: Apparently Oscar has several ways to define shipping; updating answer to cover methods defined in the dashboard!

---

Once you have [forked Oscar's shipping app](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/fork_app.html), you can override the repository class and only return the shipping you want.

If you've defined your weight-based shipping through the dashboard, you can get it with the `WeightBased` model, and only return that:

forked_apps/shipping/repository.py:

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import repository
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
from . import methods

WeightBased = get_model('shipping', 'WeightBased')

class Repository(repository.Repository):
    def get_available_shipping_methods(self, basket, user=None,
            shipping_addr=None, request=None, **kwargs):

        if shipping_addr:
            weightbased_set =  WeightBased.objects.all()

            if weightbased_set:
                return ( list(weightbased_set), )

        # If no address was specified, or weight-based options are
        # not available, return the "Reserve" shipping option
        return ( methods.Reserve(), )
```

forked_apps/shipping/methods.py:

```
from oscar.apps.shipping import methods

class Reserve(methods.NoShippingRequired):
    code = 'RESERVE'
    name = 'Reserve'
    description = 'Items will be reserved at the warehouse for 7 days'
```

Delaying payment would involve forking the [payment app](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/apps/payment.html), and would be worth its own question.

The Oscar documentation also has some good information on further customization of shipping options in the "[How to configure shipping](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_configure_shipping.html)" section.

Comment: @JacobHumes I understand you explanations. I have an error. And will add more to my request so you can understand where I am. Thank you

Comment: I have added more details above, could you take a look and advice?  Thank you. @Jacob Hume